# How to create new entry for each item in JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, json, drop-down-menu

I have a JSON file. It looks like this:

```
{
"AL": "Alabama",
"AK": "Alaska",
"AS": "American Samoa",
"AZ": "Arizona",
"AR": "Arkansas",
"CA": "California"
}
```

How do I loop through every entry in this JSON file and add it to this dropdown?

```html
<select name="states" id="states">
<option value="Alabama">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your question is really too broad in its current state. What specific problem are you having? Reading the JSON? Parsing the JSON into JS? Looping over the entries? Creating the new options? Adding the options to the select? Something else?

Answer (score -1):

please try the below code.

```
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<select id="a"></select>
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
    function add(){


var json = JSON.parse('{"AL": "Alabama","AK": "Alaska","AS": "American Samoa","AZ": "Arizona","AR": "Arkansas","CA": "California"}');
console.log(json);


for( x in json)
 {
    document.querySelector('#a').innerHTML += "<option value='" + json[x] + "'>" + json[x] + "</option>"
}


}
</script>
```